# How to compute the Euclidean distance in a list of vectors in SageMath

Tags: python, euclidean-distance, sage

I have a list of vectors and I would like to compute the shortest distance between any pair of vectors in the list.

```
V = [vector([x,y]) for x in [0..1] for y in [0..1]]

output: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I would like to get the distance from each vector to another vector. The format of the output is not important, but it could be something similar to

```
L=[(1,1,sqrt(2)),(1,sqrt(2),1),(1,sqrt(2),1),(sqrt(2),1,1)]
```

where L[i] returns a tuple that has the distance from V[i] to V[j] (i != j).

At the end I take the smallest number, in this case 1. The vectors I am working with may not always have integers, but they would be over the real numbers.

I could write a function that computes this, but I feel Sage might have it implemented already and I do not know about it. Eventually, I would like to perform this calculation for vectors of higher dimensions. Is there a way to this in Sage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `[(v-w).norm() for v in V for w in V]` give you what you want? Or `[[(v-w).norm() for v in V] for w in V]`? The first is one big list, while the second is a nested list, one for each v in V.

The `norm` method gives the length of a vector, so this computes the length of each difference `v-w` for pairs in your set of vectors.

Edit: to remove 0 from the list(s): `[[(v-w).norm() for v in V if v != w] for w in V]` or `[[(v-w).norm() for v in V if v-w] for w in V]` in the case of nested lists, or `[(v-w).norm() for v in V for w in V if v-w]` or `[(v-w).norm() for v in V for w in V if v != w]` in the unnested case.

Comment: This is very close. This still computes the distance of a vector to itself, which is zero. Then something like `sorted([(v-w).norm() for v in V for w in V])[len(V)]` gives what I want. Thanks! I did not know about `norm` method.

Comment: By the way `abs(v)` also gives the length of a vector `v`, as does `norm(v)`.